connecting exchange server in power bi
I've just tried to connect exchange server in order to download attachment files
and faced with below error!
Powerbi-> data sources-> exchange server(online)
any help?


I was able to fix the error by changing email permissions and giving full control over email folders
The next issue I encountered was that I need to provide a connection string for automatic update and I don't know where to specify that.
